# Interpreting Results of MLR

Tags: r, linear-regression

I Have recently prefromed an MLR results shown here:

```
    lm(formula = Total_Deaths_Per_Million ~ GDP_Per_Capita + GNI_Per_Capita + 
    Trade_Percentage_Of_GDP + People_Using_Basic_Sanitation_Percentage_Of_Population + 
    Total_Population + Use_Of_IMF_Credit_US + Human_Development_Index + 
    Stringency_Index, data = final_test_combined_dataset) 

    Residuals:
      3       6       8      12      16      17      18      20      21      22 
-1.4022  1.6817 -0.4956 -1.9019  2.3436  0.2513  2.3864  0.1713  1.4964 -4.5310 

    Coefficients:
                                                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                                             4.995e+00  9.839e+01   0.051    0.968
GDP_Per_Capita                                         -1.696e-02  3.377e-02  -0.502    0.704
GNI_Per_Capita                                          8.479e-03  1.174e-02   0.722    0.602
Trade_Percentage_Of_GDP                                -5.625e-01  5.671e-01  -0.992    0.503
People_Using_Basic_Sanitation_Percentage_Of_Population  7.111e-01  1.742e-01   4.082    0.153
Total_Population                                        2.843e-07  2.511e-07   1.132    0.461
Use_Of_IMF_Credit_US                                   -5.576e-08  4.706e-08  -1.185    0.446
Human_Development_Index                                -1.033e+02  2.145e+02  -0.482    0.714
Stringency_Index                                        2.460e+00  8.249e-01   2.982    0.206

Residual standard error: 6.535 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9953,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.958 
F-statistic: 26.65 on 8 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.1488
```

Questions:

1. Why for the residuals are they displayed as 3, 6, 8, 12, 16 etc.?
2. Can anyone share any good resources for interpreting the rest of the results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my first MLR I have run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Output gives you some information about the distribution of residuals. I can reproduce a case that R prints the absolute residuals like that instead of their distribution when I put only like 5 observations into the data. Did you sample a few rows?
2. In the multiple linear regression model, the coefficients of the independent variables indicate the effect of a one unit change in the corresponding variable on the expected value of the dependent variable y (when all other independent variables are held constant). If the estimate of a coefficient x for example is -0.35, this means that if x increases by one unit, then the expected value of the dependent variable y decreases by the value 0.35.

I was introduced to regression with the Book "Principles of Econometrics" (R. Carter Hill, William E. Griffiths and Guay C. Lim) which I can highly recommend, it has no R context though.

Comment: Yes I used 10 rows corresponding to 10 different countries, I have just noticed whilst counting these rows that the residual values are the same as the row numbers. Not sure why this has happened?

Comment: Thank you for the book reccomendation will check this out.